# Add few variable based on the existing CSV and append to the existing JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

We do have one csv and one json.
Based on the values inside the CSV, we need to modify the json.

For instance:

Input CSV:

```
myID,goID1,goID2,goID3

a123-b456-c789,10.0.0.0/16,10.1.0.0/16,10.2.0.0/16

a123-b456-c789,11.0.0.0/16,11.1.0.0/16,11.2.0.0/16
```

Input JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "123",
    "name": "test1",
    "goValues": [
      {
        "id": "456",
        "name": "10.3.0.0",
        "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
        "status": "active",
        "goID": "10.3.0.0/16"
      },
      {
        "id": "789",
        "name": "10.4.0.0",
        "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
        "status": "active",
        "goID": "10.4.0.0/16"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, here I need to (update) add the extra `goValues` which we get that from the CSV.  inside the `goValues` id and status are generated later.

All we need is to do is to append the values of name, `goID`, `myID`.
name should be the same as the `goID` without subnet, `goID` is `goID`, `myID` is `myID`.

Convert this to json as below:

```
{
  "name": "10.0.0.0",
  "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
  "goID": "10.0.0.0/16"
},
{
  "name": "10.1.0.0",
  "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
  "goID": "10.1.0.0/16"
},
{
  "name": "10.2.0.0",
  "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
  "goID": "10.2.0.0/16"
}
```

and append to the input_JSON:

```
[
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "test1",
      "goValues": [
        {
          "id": "456",
          "name": "10.3.0.0",
          "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
          "status": "active",
          "goID": "10.3.0.0/16"
        },
        {
          "id": "789",
          "name": "10.4.0.0",
          "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
          "status": "active",
          "goID": "10.4.0.0/16"
        },
        {
          "name": "10.0.0.0",
          "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
          "goID": "10.0.0.0/16"
        },
        {
          "name": "10.1.0.0",
          "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
          "goID": "10.1.0.0/16"
        },
        {
          "name": "10.2.0.0",
          "myID": "a123-b456-c789",
          "goID": "10.2.0.0/16"
        }
      ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
csv = pd.read_csv('csv.csv')

with open('json.json') as f:
    j = json.load(f)

for idx, row in csv.iterrows():
    for goID in row.filter(like='goID'):
        j[0]['goValues'].append({
            'name': goID.split('/')[0],
            'myID': row['myID'],
            'goID': goID,
        })

with open('json.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(j, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: what if you have the json in the code it self but not the separate file. i mean what if the jinput json is in the file ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 87, in <module>
    payload = json.load(payload.json)
NameError: name 'payload' is not defined

Comment: the code is : 
```
        for idx, row in csv.iterrows():
            for network in row.filter(like='network'):
                networkData['cidrs'].append({
                    'name': network.split('/')[0],
                    'rail': 'public',
                    'tID': row['tID'],
                    'cidrBlock': network,
                })

        with open('payload.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(networkData, f, indent=2)

        payload = json.load(payload.json)
        print (payload)
```